# XPath - select text after certain node

Tags: xpath

I have found a node, now i need to select sibling text after it:

[image]

In my case i need to get the text `: 10 January`

How do i do this?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Try this:

`//foo/following-sibling::text()[1]`

(replace `//foo/` with your current XPath expression.

With this XML:

```
<data>
<foo>foo</foo>
bar
<baz>baz</baz>
</data>
```

it gives `bar` as output.

Comment: To be pedantic for a second, the whitespace around `bar` is significant, so the output isn't *exactly* `bar`. You might want to use `normalize-space(//foo/following-sibling::text()[1])`

Comment: What if I have several similar structures and the only identifier is the `foo` text, between the `<foo>` tags. Can I use `foo` and follow sibiling. I appreciate if you could update your answer!

Comment: @WayneBurkett `normalize-space` only returns 1 `string`. How do you return all `matches` normalized in XPath 1.0 ?