# XPATH: Select text after node

Tags: xml, xpath

```
<div class="container-body">

    <div class="rule"><hr></div>
    <h3>Software version:</h3>
    10.0.0

    <div class="rule"><hr></div>
    <h3>Operating system(s):</h3>
    AIX, Linux, Windows

    <div class="rule"><hr></div>
    <h3>Reference #:</h3>
7042947

<div class="rule"><hr></div>
<h3>Modified date:</h3>
<p>2015-04-02</p>

</div>
```

Given the above code segment, How do I get the values 10.0.0; AIX,Linx,Windows; and 7042947 considering that they are not within any HTML tags.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8818218/3166303

Comment: How do you mean they are not within any HTML tags? They are within `<div>` and `</div>`. If they were truly not within any XML tags (or HTML tags, but that is not the same), it wouldn't be parsable as XML or HTML to begin with.

Answer (score 3):

As often, the answer is: "it depends". If you *just* need the non-whitespace text nodes within `<div>`, you can use the following, but it will select any child under `<div>` that is a text node (but not grand-children).

```
div/text()[normalize-space()]
```

If you only want the text nodes following `<div class="rule">...` and `<h3>` explicitly, you can instruct XPath to do so:

```
div
    /div[@class="rule"]
    /following-sibling::*[1]
    /self::h3
    /following-sibling::text()[1]
```

Which means:

- select `<div>`
- select every child `<div>` with attribute `class="rule"`
- select the first *following sibling* element
- only select this following sibling element if it is `h3`
- then (if all previous succeed) select the first following text node

Or if you want to select any non-whitespace text node in the whole document that is preceded by a `<h3>` you can do the following:

```
//text()[normalize-space()][preceding-sibling::*[1]/self::h3]
```

This last expression is specifically crafted to ignore any comment nodes or PI instructions and only select the text node if its *immediate preceding sibling element* is `<h3>`, otherwise it will ignore it.

Hopefully the above examples give you enough tools to construct your XPath, but if your requirement isn't in there and you can't figure it out, just ask.

Answer (score 1):

XPath may be simple as:

```
"*/text()"
```

or as:

```
"*/text()[normalize-space()]"
```

Depends on the library.

Comment: No, it does not depend on a library, it depends on whether whitespace was stripped prior to applying the XPath to the XDM instance. Unless you explicitly strip it, it isn't. The second form will not select whitespace-only nodes. The first form will.

Comment: @Abel - If we replace the `<hr>` to `<hr/>` and use `XmlDocument` class from .NET Framework, the xpath-expression `*/text()` gets only 3 nodes. But HtmlAgilityPack gets 10 nodes. So I suggested that the final result depends on the library.

Comment: Using the XmlDocument class will select whitespace nodes also, depending on your parsing settings. HtmlAgility returns a DOM tree, after which the effect is the same. You are suggesting it depends how you turn HTML into an XDM, and indeed the are many ways (strip whitespace, append default attributes, parse external entities, validate dtd etc), but the xpath is irrespective and ignorant of that.

Answer (score 0):

To get  AIX, Linux, Windows

use the following xpath,

```
//h3[2]/following-sibling::text()[1]
```

similarly create other xpaths to get your string.

Comment: This may select false positives, i.e. if the structure is `<h3>bla</h3><h4>foo</h4>bar` (h3 followed by h4 followed by text), your expression will select `bar`. But possibly that leniency is what the OP wants...