# How to find xpath of an element under a heading

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

in a Web page :

```
<h3 class="xh-highlight">Units Currently On Bed List</h3>
"[total beds=0]
"
```

i want to find xpath of total beds=0.
how can i do?

Comment: Show how you tried. Also update your HTML sample because provided seem to be incomplete

Comment: <form method="POST" action="BedListAdmin" class="">
<table style="width: 75%;" class="">
<tbody class=""><tr class="">
 <th class="">Number Of Beds</th>
 <th class="">Unit</th>
 <th class="">Interval</th>
 <th class="">Select All &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="chbox" onclick="toggleAll(this)">
</th>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
<div class="center">
<input type="submit" name="action" value="Remove Unit" class="">
<input type="hidden" name="BedListAdminServlet.originOfUpdate" value="viewList">
</div>
</form>


<h3 class="">Bed List</h3>[total beds=0]

Comment: i tried : //*[text()='[total beds=0]']

Comment: Your HTML still doesn't allow to identify parent node for required text node... Try `//*[normalize-space()='[total beds=0]']`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question and your comment are a bit contradictory. Do you want to find the text after a heading or do you want to find the element containing the text `[total beds=0]`? Also, how exact do you want to navigate your document?

To find a text after any `h3` element you can use this: `//h3/following-sibling::text()[1]` (see [XPath - select text after certain node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818085/xpath-select-text-after-certain-node)).

To find a text after an `h3` element with the class "xs-highlight" you can use this: `//h3[@class='xh-highlight']/following-sibling::text()[1]`

To be even more precise you can also look for the heading text: `//h3[@class='xh-highlight' and text()='Units Currently On Bed List']/following-sibling::text()[1]`

This doesn't match the html in your first comment however, so you might want to adjust the header class and text values. Also, it will find any first text even if there are other elements between it and the `h3` element.

Now, your second comment makes it seem you actually want to find the element containing the text. The reason `//*[text()='[total beds=0]']` doesn't work is because of the newline in the text. If you can get rid of that in the source it should match, otherwise you can "ignore" it in the xpath by using `//*[normalize-space(text())='[total beds=0]']`. (This is assuming the quotes around the text in your question aren't actually in the document.)

Comment: thanku very much, //h3[contains(text(),'Bed List')]/following-sibling::text()[1] worked

Comment: when i  use object.gettext(), i am getting it as pending in debug mode. and unable to read text

Comment: To be honest that sounds like a different issue, one I can't answer with the limited information given. I'd recommend you search this website for an answer.

Comment: the text that i am talking about in an HTML page is enclosed only in <body> tag and not in any other. The xpath that i am using , i can locate the object - this i am confirming by using xpath helper. But if i use this xpath to return the text i get nothing. and below is the HTML code where i want to find is [total bed=0]

Comment: <a href="/csg/">Return to Server</a><br>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html40/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
 <title>List Management</title>
 <link rel='stylesheet' href='/csg/Configuration.cgi/www/style/menu.css' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
<div id="links"> <img src="/csg/Configuration.cgi/www/images/gems_logo_lg.png" alt="Systems">
<br>
<a href="Home">Home</a>
<br>
<a href="Dashboard">Dashboard<span>Server information.</span></a>
</div>

Comment: <div id="content">
<table style='width: 75%;text-align: left;border: 0px;'>
 <tr><td style='border: 0px;text-align: left;'><h2>Current sys List:</h2></td></tr>
 <tr><td style='border: 0px;text-align: left;'>
</table>
<h3>Units Currently On  List</h3>[total bed=0]
<form method='POST' action='sysListAdmin'>
<table style='width: 75%;'>
<tr>
 <th>Number</th>
 <th>Unit</th>
 <th>Interval</th>
 <th>Select All &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="chbox" onclick="toggleAll(this)">
</th>
</tr>
</table>

Comment: <div class='center'>
<INPUT TYPE=submit NAME='action' VALUE='Remove Unit'>
<input TYPE=hidden name="ListAdminServlet.originOfUpdate" VALUE="viewList">
</div>
</form>
<!-- Javascript fuction to select/deselect all checkboxes in a form. -->
<script type='text/javascript'>
function toggleAll(toggleBox) {
var currForm = toggleBox.form;
var isChecked = toggleBox.checked;
for (var elementIdx=0; elementIdx<currForm.elements.length; elementIdx++) {
if (currForm.elements[elementIdx].type == 'checkbox') {
currForm.elements[elementIdx].checked = isChecked;
}
}
}
</script>

Comment: <div class='center'>
<INPUT TYPE=submit NAME='action' VALUE='Remove Unit'>
<input TYPE=hidden name="ListAdminServlet.originOfUpdate" VALUE="viewList">
</div>
</form>
<!-- Javascript fuction to select/deselect all checkboxes in a form. -->
<script type='text/javascript'>
function toggleAll(toggleBox) {
var currForm = toggleBox.form;
var isChecked = toggleBox.checked;
for (var elementIdx=0; elementIdx<currForm.elements.length; elementIdx++) {
if (currForm.elements[elementIdx].type == 'checkbox') {
currForm.elements[elementIdx].checked = isChecked;
}
}
}
</script>

Comment: <h3>sys List</h3>[total bed=0]
<form method='POST' action='sysListAdmin'>
<table style='width: 75%;'>
<tr>
 <th>&nbsp;</th>
 <th>Specifier</th>
 <th>IP</th>
 <th>HIS Mapping</th>
 <th>Interval</th>
 <th>Data Services</th>
 <th>Select All &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="chbox" onclick="toggleAll(this)">
</th>
</tr>
</body>
</html>